# Restricting access to files within website from outside

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to restrict the access of files / URLs within my website from outside.
i.e., if a user types a URL http://www.mysite.com/url1, I want him to be redirected to homepage. However, the user should be able to access mysite/url1 once he is on mysite (by clicking some links etc). I tried using .htaccess with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mysite.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule .*url1.*$ /? [R,NS,NC,L]
```

When someone types mysite/url1 they are redirected to homepage which is what I want. However, when I try to access mysite/url1 from within my website, it is still redirected to my site. (and I don't want this redirection to happen if the call is from my program).

Can someone help, please.

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
RewriteRule ^(url1)($|/) - [L]
```

BEFORE an other rewrite.